# Regex to match a page number in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to match the following barcode string:

```
Invoice CO1234 1234567890 06.01.2016 06.01.2016 USD 6.72 1 1

Elements explanation by possition:
1st - document type
2nd - document related number
3rd - document related number
4th - date
5th - date
6th - Currency
7th - Sum
8th - page number ( i need the regex to match when the page is equal to "1")
9th - total pages
```

Everything **except** the **Sum** will be the same length. The sum may grow up to 100 or 1000...

In this case is it possible to match the page number?

> Note: Matching the string backwards is not an option because there
>   might be some attached additional documents to the one above and the
>   string will get much longer.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I was really confused about what you were trying to find. I thought the explanations were a part of the barcode string. Maybe my fault for not knowing barcodes.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work

```
(\d+)\s+\d+$ <-- Match in 1st capturing group
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR4vC2/1)**

It seems you want to do `forward matching`. In that case you can use

```
^(?:[^\s]+\s){7}([^\s]+) <-- Match in 1st capturing group
```

From you previous questions it seems, you are using `vbscript`. In that case, you can use this

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(?:[^\s]+\s){7}([^\s]+)"
Dim input As String = "Invoice CO1234 1234567890 06.01.2016 06.01.2016 USD 6.72 1 1"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
```

**[Idoene Demo](http://ideone.com/okzYCL)**

Comment: Nice. It really matches the group. Can you make it to match exactly the number "1" from that group ?

Comment: @changer6360 if you can tell the language you are using then I can tell

Comment: I will not use any language in this case. I have to insert this regex in an application that then matches the regex of a scanned barcode and according to the results it will do specific action.

Comment: @changer6360 which application are you using?

Comment: It's a specific application for document processing that is not relevant in this case. The thing is that it has only the option for regex matching(no script at all). Basically, I need pure regex solution for this problem, if possible of course.

Comment: @changer6360 i don't think it will be possible. The regex will match all the lines if the pattern is found

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expression to achieve what you want. You can just split the string on the field separator ' ' and take the 8th field.
For example using python :

```
input = "Invoice CO1234 1234567890 06.01.2016 06.01.2016 USD 6.72 1 1"
input.split(' ')[7]
```

Alternatively if you really want to use regex, you can use something like that :

```
import re
input = "Invoice CO1234 1234567890 06.01.2016 06.01.2016 USD 6.72 1 1"
re.search(r"^([^ ]* ){7}([^ ]*)", input).group(2)
```